# use a mysql query result to do another query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 table table1 contains an userid and a postid.  Table2 contains a userid and a username.  I want to return all the userids with a certain postid and then use those userids to query table2 and get the usernames.

Is there a way to go about this? I have tried join statement and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Add the query that you tried in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN function:

```
select username, userid from `table2` where userid in (select userid from `table` where postid = <condition>)
```

Comment: Now what if I want to return comment_id from table along with the username and userid?

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you please add the table create stements to your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.postid, A.userid, B.username FROM
tableA AS A JOIN tableB AS B ON A.userid=B.userid
```

select post id, user id from tableA username from tableB. Join these 2 different table columns when tableA's userid is equal to tableB's userid.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on the common columns

```
select t1.postid, t1.userid, t2.username
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid
where t1.postid = 2
```

Comment: But it has to be where I set a specific postid.  So like if posted = 2 return the userid and then search table2 based on the userid to get the username

Comment: I added that into the query at the end

Comment: Now what if I want to return a comment_id from table1 also. Assume now table1 contains a comment_id field

Comment: Then add it in the select part. You should really take a SQL tutorial. This is so very basic and you won't get far without basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.postid, t1.userid, t2.username
from table1 t2
left join table1 t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid
where t1.postid = <your postid>
```